# Pentaho: how to use metedata injection in text file input step?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-spoon

I am new in pentaho and need some more information from experts. I have a transformation, where I need to read a file and then change the data from it.  Problem is that the number of colums in the file can change every time (it can be in this month 10 colums in file, in next 12). I have read that I must use a „Metadata Injection“ step for such cases, but I can not find a good example for it. Can someone explain or show simple example how this Metadata injection generally works?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://www.ibridge.be/?p=194

Comment: It would probably help greatly if you could post some sample file structures, both for input and output.

Comment: There is a file of samples that comes with the Spoon download. Look in \...yourpath...\data-integration\samples\transformations\meta-inject. These are often very helpful.